# cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

In ionic3 page I want to open modal from a function of a click  event

```
export class HomePage {

  ....
  ....
  ....

  loadPos() {
    var randomLocations = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getLocations(5, this.map.getBounds());

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(randomLocations[i]);
      this.map.entities.push(pin);
      //Add a click event handler to the pushpin.
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', this.pushpinClicked);
    }
    console.log("pins added")

    pushpinClicked(e) {
      HomePage.prototype.openModal()
    }

    openModal() {
      const myModal = this.modal.create(ModalPage)
      myModal.present()
    }
  }
```

When I run openModal() function from ionic-buttun it works but when I run the function from pushpin click event i got this error :

> cannot read property 'create' of undefined

What can I do to open that modal from click event?
What

Comment: try `this.openModal()` instead - though you may need `this.pushpinClicked = this.pushpinClicked.bind(this)` in your class `constructor()`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change

```
pushpinClicked(e) {
    HomePage.prototype.openModal()
}
```

to

```
pushpinClicked(e) {
    this.openModal()
}
```

Reason being that fields such as `this.modal` aren't in the prototype object. You can see an example of this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i7wwfb Run and check the console to see the difference.

Comment: may need `this.pushpinClicked = this.pushpinClicked.bind(this)` in your class `constructor()` since `pushpinClicked` is called by an event handler?

Comment: yes you are right thanks but I also needed to bind event  function  this.pushpinClicked.bind(this)